# Prove by test integrabilty that: $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} \left|\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}\right|\, dx < +\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

how we prove that the function $\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2-1}$ is in $L^1(]0,+\infty[)$ using the tests of convegence integral? I calculate is and i found that $$\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} \left|\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}\right|\, dx < +\infty$$, but i want to prove that this function is in $L^1(]0,+\infty[)$ using the tests of integrability of integral.

Thank you in advance

Comment: AT infinity use 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{3/2}\ln x}{x^2-1} = 0$$
That is there exists $A>0$ such that $x>A$ implies 

$$ |\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}|\le \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$$

At $x=0$ use

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^{1/2}\ln x}{x^2-1} = 0$$
 That is there exists $a>0$ such that $0<x<a$ implies 

$$ |\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}|\le \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}$$

At $x=1$ there singularity is fake since, $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln x}{x-1} = (\ln x)'|_{x=1} =1$$

Answer (score 1):

> At infinity use

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{3/2}\ln x}{x^2-1} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^{2}}{x^2-1}\cdot\frac{\ln x}{x^{1/2}} =\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\ln x^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}} = 0$$
That is there exists $A>0$ such that $x>A$ implies

$$ |\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}|\le \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$$

> At $x=0$ use

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^{1/2}\ln x}{x^2-1} = \frac12 \lim_{x\to0}x^{1/2}\ln x^{1/2} = 0$$
 That is there exists $a>0$ such that $0<x<a$ implies

$$ |\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}|\le \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}$$

> At $x=1$ there singularity is fake since,

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln x}{x-1} = (\ln x)'|_{x=1} =1$$

Answer (score -1):

Notice that $|\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}| \leq \min\{x^{1/2}, x^{3/2}\}$ and that the RHS is integrable because $p < 1$, $p > 1$ respectively. So by the comparison test, the integral in question is finite, hence $\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1} \in L^1$.

Comment: $x^2-1$ not $x^2+1$

Comment: Please, how we prouve that $|\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2-1}| \leq \min \{x^{1/2},x^{3/2}\}$? and we have $x^2-1$ not $x^2+1$

Comment: @GuyFsone it's true either way; sign has been fixed.

Comment: @user487908   see that there is a heavy singularity  at $x=1$ which you forgotten. so the inequality is not enough

Comment: exercise: there exists a continuous extension of $\ln(x)/(x^2 - 1)$ from $(0, 1)\cup(1,\infty)$ to $(0, \infty)$. Regardless, the upper-bound still holds, hence too the comparison test.

Comment: but the continuity implies that the function is $L^1_{loc}$ not $L^1$

Comment: a singularity at $x=1$ is a set of measure zero, so $L^1$ ignores this.

Comment: You can integrate the function numerically on $(0,\infty)$ and see that it yields a finite value, hence it's not only in $L^1_{loc}$ but $L^1((0,\infty))$.

Comment: More importantly, it is everywhere upper-bounded by a function which is $L^1$ integrable, hence it too must be $L^1$ integrable. This is the virtue of the comparison test!